# Is there a utility that displays hotkeys for the current application?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

To speed up my compyuter use I'm trying to use as many hotkeys as possible. But because I'm working in many applications it is really hard to remember all those shortcuts.

I'm looking for a program that looks at what application is currently in use by me, and displays a list of possible hotkeys I want to use.

Example: I'm writing a document in Word, and the utility program shows a list of hotkeys I could use in Word.

With such a program I could learn the shortcut keys much faster.

Does such a utility exist?

Comment: I don't think there's any standard way for a program to publish the information about what keyboard shortcuts it recognizes, so I have my doubts about this. But I couldn't say it's impossible.

Comment: The utilty could get shortcut lists from a webservice or something?

Comment: Please specify your operating system. For Mac OS X, there are [solutions](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/).

Comment: +1 @ Alwin, great idea, hope somebody runs with it. Some how code the program to know which window is on top, then pull the info from a web database.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such program. There is no way for a programm to determine what hotkeys are used by another application.
The only way of achiving sth. like this would be to save lists of available hotkeys for a bunch of programms that are shown each time the application is active.

Comment: Well to just show the list of standard hotkeys for the application I'm using would be great. If someone changes or adds keyboard shortcuts they are on their own :)

Answer (score 0):

What applications are you interested in?  Usually, they provide a list of shortcuts, or you can find it online.

Examples: [Word](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=7439), [Photoshop](http://www.nobledesktop.com/shortcuts-photoshopcs5-pc.html) & [iMovie](http://www.apple.com/support/imovie/shortcuts/)